# Get name of file where the cell is running from in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Lets say I'm running some code in Spyder, cell by cell.

Is there a way for me to obtain a variable, like `__file__` that indicates the same of the file that is currently being run?

Maybe something like

`__spyder_cell_file__`

I looked at the output of the command `dir()` and nothing hinted at the functionality.

It would be nice if I could get to the point in my script, that would programmatically:

1. Save the current working file
2. Copy it to some known directory for archival purposes

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no such thing in our current stable version (as of January/2019 it is 3.3.2). However, we could add something like that for our next major version (Spyder 4, to be released later this year).

Please open an issue at [this repo](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-kernels) to discuss if/how we should implement this.